# random forest regression low score

Tags: scikit-learn, regression, random-forest

I'm trying to use random forest regression for predicting a car's price. I got data from cars.com, cleaned the data, kept some features(year, mileage, exteriorColor etc.), while categorical features didn't seem work with the algorithm, so I set dummy variables for categorical features( because only numerical feature works with tress??), I got low score.

The final data looks like this:

```
Year    Model   Price   Mileage Engine  CityFuelEconomy HighwayFuelEconomy  ExteriorColor
2013     2      6900    37100    3.0          20                30               1
```

I performed random forest by default, and also with parameter tuning by GridSearch, both results are not ideal.

```
#by default
In:   from sklearn.metrics import explained_variance_score
      explained_variance_score(train_y, model.predict(train_x))
Out:  0.5569482176630063

In:   model.score(test_x, test_y)
Out:  0.5299303064708601

Train MAE: 993.199536787152
Test MAE: 1094.8346295258416

#GridSearch
Best Score is: 0.5305298726822617
Best Parameters are: {'criterion': 'mse', 'max_depth': 15, 'max_features': 3,
                        'min_samples_leaf': 3, 'min_samples_split': 7, 'n_estimators': 500}

forest.score(X_val, y_val)
Score: 0.56
```

I'm new to machine learning, I don't know which algorithm better fits what kind of dataset, can anyone help me with improvement of this or possible reasons of what might happened? thanks!

Comment: how many samples does the data have ?

Comment: hi, 1000, 700 training set, 300 test, @YOLO

Comment: This is hard to answer, try some other models too and see if you get different results.